# Problem while deploying a Django app with Apache2 on Ubuntu

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, apache2

I've been trying to deploy a Django app on Ubuntu 18.04 using Apache2 for the past couple of days now, and it still doesn't work.

My apache2 config is:

```
<VirtualHost *:1337>
    <Directory /var/www/LGSM_webpanel/LGSM_webpanel>
            <Files wsgi.py>
                    Require all granted
            </Files>
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/LGSM-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/LGSM-access.log combined
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/LGSM_webpanel/LGSM_webpanel/wsgi.py
    WSGIDaemonProcess LGSM_webpanel python-path=/var/www/LGSM_webpanel
    WSGIprocessGroup LGSM_webpanel
    DocumentRoot /var/www
</VirtualHost>
```

However, for some reason, when I access http://localipofthemachine:1337 I just get the google chrome error Connection refused.
Now, the server works when I use manage.py runserver, and I can fully access it, but when I use apache, I just get this error.

The apache logs are also empty by the way.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212051/discussion-on-question-by-charles-problem-while-deploying-a-django-app-with-apac).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to add `Listen 1337` in the virtual host configuration, i.e.

```
Listen 1337
<VirtualHost *:1337>
    # your configuration
    # etc
</VirtualHost>
```

Second, make sure that the apache user `www-data` can access your webapp files by running `chown www-data:www-data -R /var/www/LGSM_webpanel`.